# React Native: new items added to FlatList not reacting to updated state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

in my react native app I use mobx to handle app data state, I have a list of items, and each item will render differently if the user is premium or not, new items can be added to the list if the user scrolls down for example.

My problem is this, **when user premium status changes, old items render properly (premium status changes), but for items that were added after initial render (for example, user scrolled down and new items were added via pagiantion), the old items doesn't show proper premium status for some reason...**

I checked and both my components are wrapped by observer...

FlatList component (notice renderItem method)

```
const keyExtractor = (item) => item.id.toString;

const renderItem = ({item}) => <MatchLikeCardAlt like={item}></MatchLikeCardAlt>;


<FlatList
                data={root.mapStore.sortedBlurredMatches}
     
                keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
                renderItem={renderItem}
            />
```

My FlatList item component is pretty simple, see how I render either part of the component according to the user premium status.

```
<TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={1} onPress={() => { clickedUser(item) }} style={{ width: '50%', height: 385, marginBottom: 0, position: 'relative', overflow: 'hidden', borderWidth: 0, borderColor: 'rgb(235,235,235)' }}>
                { root.userStore.user.isPremiumActive == 1 ?
                

                <View style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', position: 'relative', overflow: 'hidden', backgroundColor: 'white', overflow: 'hidden' }}>
                 
                </View>
                :
                <View style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', position: 'relative', overflow: 'hidden', backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
                    
                </View>
                }
        </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming here, but the toString used in keyExtractor is supposed to be a method, which is used by React-Native for caching and tracking item re-ordering, which might be causing the new items to render with old state since its pointing to the same function reference. Can you try using it as a function like

```
const keyExtractor = (item) => item.id.toString();
```